# How set up bundle id for theos console app

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, theos

How set up a bundle id for theos console app (tool)?

In my code, this

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSLog(@"MYBid: %@", bundleIdentifier");
```

always  print `(null)`

To create my tool I do this

```
$ ./theos/bin/nic.pl
NIC 2.0 - New Instance Creator
------------------------------
  [1.] iphone/application
  [2.] iphone/library
  [3.] iphone/preference_bundle
  [4.] iphone/tool
  [5.] iphone/tweak
Choose a Template (required): 4
Project Name (required): tst
Package Name [com.yourcompany.tst]:
Author/Maintainer Name [tst]: tst
```

Why isn't my bundle id "com.yourcompany.tst"?

Comment: It seems that you are making a "tool", i. e. a command-line non-Cocoa application. Those ain't got any bundle ID.

Comment: Actually they can have bundle ID. For example, if you look at the imagent in iOS 6 you can see that it's a command-line application that launched as daemon at system startup and it has bundle ID - com.apple.imagent

Answer (score 3):

The bundle id is set in the Info.plist file. If you're making a command-line tool, you can embed a Info.plist file in your executable by adding the following linker flag:

```
-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist path/to/Info.plist
```